# Unable to craft Wood Planks even with all mods removed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I don't know if it's just my version of Minecraft or any of the mods I've had installed previously, but when I take any type of wood logs and craft them, they will come out as sticks:

[image: Wood to Sticks]

I don't know if this is any of my mods so I'll list them below. I tried uninstalling them all but I'm still having this issue. I'm playing on Minecraft 1.7.10, not using any texture packs:

- Aroma1997Core
- DCModularLoader
- FloatableRails
- MicDoodle8Core
- Player API
- SmartCore
- SomniaCore
- SanAndreasManagerPack
- AdminWeapons
- AdvancedArmory
- AllUWant
- BetterBuildersWands
- BetterChests (Removed)
- ClaySolidersMod (Removed)
- DogCatPlus
- DualHotbar
- ExtraDoors
- Eyemod
- FlansMod
- GlacticCraft Core and Planets
- IChunUtil
- HatsMod
- InstantMassiveStructers
- Minenautica
- Mo' Bends
- MorphMod
- MobArmorMod
- NeXTechMod
- realismMod
- SmartMoving
- SmartRendering
- Somnia
- TransportTerminalMod
- Xaero's Minimap.

Comment: Start disabling mods, until it doesn't happen anymore.

Comment: Not helping, I just took them all out of my mods folder and I'm still having this glitch

Comment: Wood as in logs, or wood as in planks? Do you have any resource pack? Could you screenshot you crafting this? Taking mods out of your mods folder may not have disabled all non-Forge mods.

Comment: Anything else you need added?

Comment: Obviously one of your mods adds this recipe into the game. Like @Frank said, remove mods one by one until it stop happening. The last mod you removed will be the one with the recipe.

Comment: @Player Disable all mods. Still have the problem? Delete the mods part from your question ([edit]). Don't have it? Add mods few by few, 'till you get the glitch. Delete those mods. Done.

Answer (score 5):

You can install [Minetweaker](http://minetweaker3.powerofbytes.com/) mod and edit your recipes.

This is easiest way to do so, you can still search for mod adding the recipe and possibly try to find if it has config for disabling that, but if not, you have no more choices.

Using Minetweaker is kind of easy. However if you put it on server, all the clients need that, too. Best is to ask developer of the Modpack to do so, if you use any Modpack made by someone or play on someone's server.

Minetweaker is maintained by Scripts. Easy scripts.

- First, you need to install the mod, after restart, there will be `scripts` folder in main directory of server/save.
- Open that directory and create new file. It can have any name, it only needs to be `.zs` type, for example `recipes.zs`. But it is normal txt file, only name is changed.
- Open the file in any text editor, then you need to fabricate the order to change the recipe.
- There are few methods for adding and removing recipes, you can get whole documentation on [MT wiki](http://minetweaker3.powerofbytes.com/wiki/Main_Page). We will use the method to remove one particular recipe (first is output, then the used recipe), that is :

  recipes.removeShapeless(<minecraft:stick>, [<minecraft:log:*>]);
- So you will write down the line to remove the recipe, that would make stick from any vanilla log. However there is also another block id for new logs, so you can add one more line:

  recipes.removeShapeless(<minecraft:stick>, [<minecraft:log2:*>]);
- Then ingame just write `/mt reload` or restart server. But command is enough. If you play on server, only server needs the file and it overrides the recipe instantly for everyone on server.
- Now there are two possibilities. First, if it writes just "Scripts reloaded", you are fine and you should not be able to see the recipe in NEI nor craft that item. OR it will print the error. That might happen, there are few cases that could make that.
- If the recipe is still here, we could tried to delete wrong recipe. The one could be also Shaped, or could be crafted not from `minecraft:log`, but from `ore:logWood`, aka all logs from all mods. But we can get the recipes that are in the game already, so get the stick in hand and write:

  /mt recipes hand
- That will print all recipes for such an item, into console or if too long, into `minetweaker.log` file in main directory. Look it up and find the recipes that use Logs and output sticks. Then remove that recipes as used above.

Note: If you don't know the ID of item, just put it in hand and write `/mt hand`, it will print the ID of item. Same with recipes and so. Also good idea is to use oredict in recipes, so you don't need exactly matching items. If you want to study, how it works, read the wiki linked above, or you can look for example [here, on some collected scripts](https://github.com/Dream-Master/Mods-Get-Gregged).

Note 2 : try to put logs into other slots, it usually works like that some slots are outputting something another than other slots.

Comment: Many times, the best and most long time-taking answers end up with a few votes, eg. here. This needs more upvotes :)